# Restructuring and creating a 5 x 5 summary matrix r

Tags: r, matrix, crosstab, summary, xtable

I have a dataset with three columns

The first column is ID

The second column is Intervention with **two levels** : Pre, Post

The third column is Response with **5 levels** : strongly disagree, disagree, neutral, agree, strongly agree

```
  RecordId  Intervention          Response
  26        Post                  neutral
  26        Pre                   agree
  27        Post                  Strongly Agree
  27        Pre                   strongly disagree
  29        Post                  neutral
  .         .                     .
  .         .                     .
  .         .                     .
```

The actual dataset is below

```
    df <- structure(list(record_id = c(26, 26, 27, 27, 29, 29, 30, 30, 
33, 33, 34, 34, 36, 36, 39, 39, 40, 40, 42, 42, 44, 44, 45, 45, 
46, 46, 49, 49, 50, 50, 52, 52, 53, 53, 55, 55), Intervention = c("Post", 
"Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", 
"Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", 
"Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", 
"Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre", "Post", "Pre"), 
    Response = structure(c(3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 
    5L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("strongly disagree", 
    "disagree", "neutral", "agree", "strongly agree"), class = c("labelled", 
    "factor"), label = "")), .Names = c("record_id", "Intervention", 
"Response"), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 17L, 18L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 26L, 27L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 47L, 
48L), class = "data.frame")
```

How do I convert this to a 5 x 5 matrix like this below

```
                  Post
Pre               StronglyAgree   Agree Neutral  Disagree StronglyDisagree  
StronglyAgree     ---            ---   ---      ---        ---      
Agree             ---            ---   ---      ---      ---
Neutral           ---            ---   ---      ---      ---
Disagree          ---            ---   ---      ---      ---
StronglyDisagree  ---            ---   ---      ---      ---
```

Comment: There is no data that will populate the new matrix in your current data? It's unclear what that data would be and that will impact how this operation gets done.

Comment: How are you supposed to match up the pre/post values? Are you assuming the values appear as pairs in order in the data?

Comment: @MrFlick, I have added the missing information (new column) showing the paired nature of the data. Hope this provides the missing piece of the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, this may work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
 pivot_wider(record_id, names_from = Intervention, values_from = Response) %>% 
 select(Pre, Post) %>% 
 table()

#              Post
# Pre                 strongly disagree disagree neutral agree strongly agree
#  strongly disagree                 1        0       0     0              1
#  disagree                          0        1       1     0              0
#  neutral                           0        0       0     0              0
#  agree                             0        0       3     4              0
#  strongly agree                    0        2       1     2              2
```

You can also use `spread` in the same way:

```
df %>%
 spread(Intervention, Response) %>%
 select(Pre, Post) %>%
 table()
```

Comment: Thanks Matt that is exactly what I was expecting. I did it manually and the results match.

Comment: I am getting an error, this is because I have an older version of `tidyr` and I cannot update it, is there any other version of this code that does that same thing without using `pivot_wider` function ?

Comment: @SundownBrownbear you can use `spread`. I'll add that to the answer